# AHK if/else of output from Custom Message Box Function

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey, messagebox

I've been trying to create a script that displays message boxes conditioned on  the output from another customized message box with more than 3 options.

The custom functions are taken form this thread http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/29570-function-custom-msgbox-custom-buttons/page-2

I've tried both the `CMsgbox` and the `MsgBoxV2` functions, running into the same problem. The Message `"IT WORKED!"` testing with `if(condition)` will  always appear regardless of whether pressing any of the `Sym|&Go|&C` options, and the message `"worked"` will never appear regardless of actually pressing `C`, In other words no specificity or sensitivity regarding variable testing.

```
!o::
var := MsgBoxV2("Question11","Hi, what's up??","Sym|Go|C","24")
Msgbox 4,, You Pressed %var%

if (%var% = C) 
{  
    Msgbox 4,, IT WORKED!
}

IfEqual, %var%,C
{  
  Msgbox 4,, worked
}
return

!e:: 
var := CMsgbox( "s", "d", "*&Sym|&Go|&C","",1 )
Msgbox 4,, You Pressed %var%
if (%var% = C) 
{  
    Msgbox 4,, IT WORKED!
}

IfEqual, %var%,C
{  
  Msgbox 4,, worked
}
return
```

I don't know if this is because I've misunderstood the if/Else testing in ahk, or if the output from these custom functions cannot be tested, or both. 
One solution would be to figure out what type of variable %var% is, but I've not been able to find a way to figure that out either.

Thanks for reading and hope you guys can help.

here are the custom message functions for testing.

```
MsgBoxV2(Title="",Text="",Buttons="",IconPath="",Timeout="",Font="",Schriftart="Arial",Colors="||",WindowStyles="",GuiNr = "")
{
Static Stat2,Stat1
Col1:="0xFFFFFF" ,Col2:="0x000000",Col3:="0x000000", Color1:="", Color2:="", Color3:=""
Loop, Parse, Colors,`|
Color%A_Index% := (A_Loopfield = "") ? Col%A_Index% : A_Loopfield
Loop 3
Color%A_Index% := (Color%A_Index% = "") ? Col%A_Index% : Color%A_Index%
if instr(WindowStyles,"+altsubmit")
{
AltSub := "1" 
Stringreplace,WindowStyles,WindowStyles,`+altsubmit
}
Gui, Color, %Color1%,%Color1%
Gui, Font, s9
Gui, Font, %Font%, %Schriftart%
X := 20 ,Y := 20
ifexist, %IconPath%
{
Gui, Add, Picture, x20 y20 w32 h32, %IconPath%
X := 70 ,Y := 30
} else
if IconPath is integer
{
Gui, Add, Picture, x20 y20 icon%IconPath% w32 h32, %A_WinDir%\system32\shell32.dll
X := 70 ,Y := 30
}
Gui, Add, Text, x%X% y%Y% c%Color2% vStat2, %Text%
GuicontrolGet, Stat2, Pos
X2 = 10
Y2 := (Stat2Y + Stat2H < 52) ? 82 : Stat2Y + Stat2H + 30
HMax = 0
Gui, Add, Text, vStat1 +border -background
Loop, Parse, Buttons,|,`|
{
Gui, Add, Button, x%X2% w100 Y%Y2% gExButton , %A_Loopfield%
ButT%A_Index% := A_Loopfield
Guicontrolget, Button%A_Index%,Pos
if (HMax < Button%A_Index%H)
HMax := Button%A_Index%H
ABut := A_Index
X2 += 110
}
Loop %ABut%
Guicontrol, Move, Button%A_Index%,h%HMax%
Gui, %WindowStyles%
Gui, Show, Autosize Center,%Title%
Guicontrol, Move, Stat1, % "X-1 Y" Y2 - 10 " W" 1400 " h" 41 + HMax
Guicontrol, -Background +hidden, Stat1
Guicontrol, show, Stat1
Gui, +LastFound
WinGet, G_id
if Timeout !=
if Timeout is integer
settimer, Timeout, %Timeout%
Winwait, ahk_id %G_id%
retval = 0
while winexist("ahk_id " G_id)
sleep 100
if !AltSub
return ButT%retval%
else
return retval
Timeout:
if Timeout =
return
GuiClose:
Gui, destroy
return
ExButton:
MouseGetPos,,,, Control
Stringreplace,retval,Control,Button
Gui, destroy
return
}


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Custom Msgbox
; Filename: cmsgbox.ahk
; Author  : Danny Ben Shitrit (aka Icarus)
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Copy this script or include it in your script (without the tester on top).
;
; Usage:
;   Answer := CMsgBox( title, text, buttons, icon="", owner=0 )
;   Where:
;     title   = The title of the message box.
;     text    = The text to display.
;     buttons = Pipe-separated list of buttons. Putting an asterisk in front of 
;               a button will make it the default.
;     icon    = If blank, we will use an info icon.
;               If a number, we will take this icon from Shell32.dll
;               If a letter ("I", "E" or "Q") we will use some predefined icons
;               from Shell32.dll (Info, Error or Question).
;     owner   = If 0, this will be a standalone dialog. If you want this dialog
;               to be owned by another GUI, place its number here.
;
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CMsgBox( title, text, buttons, icon="", owner=0 ) {
  Global _CMsg_Result

  GuiID := 9      ; If you change, also change the subroutines below

  StringSplit Button, buttons, |

  If( owner <> 0 ) {
    Gui %owner%:+Disabled
    Gui %GuiID%:+Owner%owner%
  }

  Gui %GuiID%:+Toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop

  MyIcon := ( icon = "I" ) or ( icon = "" ) ? 222 : icon = "Q" ? 24 : icon = "E" ? 110 : icon

  Gui %GuiID%:Add, Picture, Icon%MyIcon% , Shell32.dll
  Gui %GuiID%:Add, Text, x+12 yp w180 r8 section , %text%

  Loop %Button0% 
    Gui %GuiID%:Add, Button, % ( A_Index=1 ? "x+12 ys " : "xp y+3 " ) . ( InStr( Button%A_Index%, "*" ) ? "Default " : " " ) . "w100 gCMsgButton", % RegExReplace( Button%A_Index%, "\*" )

  Gui %GuiID%:Show,,%title%

  Loop 
    If( _CMsg_Result )
      Break

  If( owner <> 0 )
    Gui %owner%:-Disabled

  Gui %GuiID%:Destroy
  Result := _CMsg_Result
  _CMsg_Result := ""
  Return Result
}

9GuiEscape:
9GuiClose:
  _CMsg_Result := "Close"
Return

CMsgButton:
  StringReplace _CMsg_Result, A_GuiControl, &,, All
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in syntax of your code. I highly suggest that you read the [Tutorial](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm) in the Docs fully! It's really well written.

What immediately popped out to me is that your Variables in your If Expressions are surrounded by percents, which is wrong.

[Here is a link to the section in the Tutorial that you need to read in order to fix your code.](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm#s61)

Try this:

```
!o::
var := MsgBoxV2("Question11","Hi, what's up??","Sym|Go|C","24")
Msgbox 4,, You Pressed %var%

if (var = "C") 
{  
    Msgbox 4,, IT WORKED!
}

!e:: 
var := CMsgbox( "s", "d", "*&Sym|&Go|&C","",1 )
Msgbox 4,, You Pressed %var%

If (var = "C")
{  
  Msgbox 4,, worked
}
return
```

The IfEqual command is pretty much deprecated and while it's still included in the latest releases, it's basically bad form to use since the `If` expression much easier to read. Also plain text excluding numbers in an expression should be surrounded by quotes. Hope this helps.